# Accessing MFC functions in python

Tags: python, function, dll, mfc

I have just recently started using python for using it with my mfc program and it has been a decent journey so far. At the moment, I am trying to access a function from my mfc dll program that has a format given below:

```
void DLLDIR DrawEllipse ( CRect, CDC* );
```

I have used extern "C" and everything and I am able to access the function. In terms of declaring its restype and arguement type, I am facing some problems at the moment. Obviously the restype would be "**None**" but I am unable to understand as to how do I declare its arguement type which are CRect and CDC*.Would be great if someone already knows how to access the MFC functions and use them as arguements in your python functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you need to wrap those structures as Python objects - either make you own, or use the 'native' Python equivalent of a rectangle (if there is one, I don't know of any). Look at Python win32 packages such as win32all to do the heavy lifting, so that you won't have to re-implement it all yourself.

Comment: Yup, I tried a lot but no luck. So, we definitely can't do this. Cheers for your reply.